# Several keyboard keys not working in VMWare (Host=Linux, Guest=Windows)

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machines, vmware-server, keyboard

I installed VMWare Server 2.0 on Ubuntu 8.* and 9.*, with Windows XP as the guest system, and several keys aren't working.

They either do nothing, or invoke the wrong keypress.

They keys are all <kbd>Arrow</kbd>  keys , <kbd>Windows</kbd>  key, <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> , <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> , <kbd>Pause</kbd>  or <kbd>Break</kbd> , <kbd>Insert (Ins)</kbd> , <kbd>Home</kbd> , <kbd>Page Up</kbd>  (<kbd>PgUp</kbd>) , <kbd>Page Down</kbd>  (<kbd>PgDn</kbd>), <kbd>Delete</kbd>  (<kbd>Del</kbd>) and <kbd>End</kbd>.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an English keyboard, just add this line to the VMware configuration file:

```
# In the file: /etc/vmware/config
xkeymap.nokeycodeMap = true
```

If you have something other than an English keyboard, the above solution won't work, apparently. So add these lines:

```
# In the file: /etc/vmware/config    
xkeymap.keycode.108 = 0x138 # Alt_R
xkeymap.keycode.106 = 0x135 # KP_Divide
xkeymap.keycode.104 = 0x11c # KP_Enter
xkeymap.keycode.111 = 0x148 # Up
xkeymap.keycode.116 = 0x150 # Down
xkeymap.keycode.113 = 0x14b # Left
xkeymap.keycode.114 = 0x14d # Right
xkeymap.keycode.105 = 0x11d # Control_R
xkeymap.keycode.118 = 0x152 # Insert
xkeymap.keycode.119 = 0x153 # Delete
xkeymap.keycode.110 = 0x147 # Home
xkeymap.keycode.115 = 0x14f # End
xkeymap.keycode.112 = 0x149 # Prior
xkeymap.keycode.117 = 0x151 # Next
xkeymap.keycode.78  = 0x46  # Scroll_Lock
xkeymap.keycode.127 = 0x100 # Pause
xkeymap.keycode.133 = 0x15b # Meta_L
xkeymap.keycode.134 = 0x15c # Meta_R
xkeymap.keycode.135 = 0x15d # Menu
```

I found the answer here:
http://communities.vmware.com/thread/177321

Comment: This has worked with for me with Ubuntu Ibex as the host.